# Django Celery not able to fetch data from particular DB schema

Tags: python-3.x, django, celery, django-celery, django-tenants

We are facing the issue fetching the data from particular schema's table which is available and the data fetching issue occurs intermediately after few hours of restart of `supervisorctl` where celery worker is defined. Below is the code mentioned:

```
with schema_context("public"):
    try:
        client = Client.objects.get(subdomain=hostname)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        client = Client.objects.using("paid").get(subdomain=hostname)
```

I have also set the connection to a particular schema using the `schema_context` function. We use RabbitMQ as middleware, and we have three different queues configured. This problem occurs in all queues. We are using the following libraries: `celery==4.4.7`, `django-celery==3.3.0` and `django-tenant-users==0.3.12`

Comment: Is this using `django-tenants` ?

Comment: Yes we are using django-tenant-users==0.3.12